# How to create a new JWT validator based on OpenID discovery URL?

Tags: ballerina

How can I create a JWT Validator based on OpenID discovery document? Instead of importing certificates to a keystore before running the service?

My goal is to use WSO2 Identity Server to issue tokens. When a ballerina microservice is called it would be configured to use two methods:
1) verify signature based on the WSO2 IS openid discovery URL.
example:
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/oidcdiscovery/.well-known/openid-configuration
The response document contains everything a developer needs to make this validation.

2) Verify token using token introspection

Can you help me start this validator?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned two requirements, let me beak my answer into two sections:

1. Use a JWT for authentication, but use OpenID discovery document to configure the JWT validator instead of manually adding configuration values.

This is currently not supported by the builtin JWT authentication provider. It is surely an interesting way to get things configured. However, you can add support for this by registering a custom authentication handler.

To do so, you can use the [AuthHandlerRegistry](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/http.html#AuthHandlerRegistry) to register you own handler and introduce a handler that can validate JWTs by looking at configured OpenID discovery information. You can look at [HTTP/auth](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/tree/master/stdlib/http/src/main/ballerina/http/auth) source to get an idea about how existing Auth Handlers work. In addition, you can look at [Auth](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/blob/6166f10be773f84695b1618b54396ae7fdcbc5d1/stdlib/auth/src/main/ballerina/auth/jwt_auth_provider.bal#L41) package to see how JWT validation actually happens.

2. Rely on OAuth2 tokens for authentication and without doing any JWT validation, use token introspection to do the validation.

Currently Ballerina only support Basic Auth and JWT based inbound authentication. We are in process of adding support for other inbound authentication mechanisms. Along with that we will look at OAuth2 based inbound authentication, which will surely involve validating tokens through introspection. I will surely update the answer when this is ready.